# Filter the output of a command as if it was text

Tags: powershell

I have a simple question, but I am also a beginner in PowerShell. I think it has to do with the fact that the output of the [Get-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Process) command (alias `ps`) is objects and not text.

I want to get a list of the services running that have the name "sql" in them.

This is what I tried so far, but every attempt returns nothing:

```
Get-Service | where {$_ -match 'sql'}

Get-Service | where {$_ -like 'sql'}

Get-Service | Select-String sql
```

I am looking for a pattern that lets me treat the output of every command as searchable text.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The other answers are right of course about your specific question of starting services that have "sql" in their name, but to answer the generic question:

You can do `Get-Service | Out-String`, and you will get the output as string, much like how Unix commands work.

Also when the output is piped to non-PowerShell commands, it does get converted to text, so for example: `Get-Service | grep sql` would work the way you wanted.

But again, like @JPBlanc says, it is good embrace the way PowerShell works, which is that the outputs are objects. It gives you way more control and keeps things simple and readable (the Unix commands with sed, awk and what not operating on text output of other command outputs can get very cryptic!).

Comment: This was the generic answer I was looking for so I mark your answer.

To get specific again, this is how I think i filter the list for SQL: 
get-service | out-string | findstr SQL

It should also be possible with select-string I think.

@mjolinor
Thanks for clarifyings. I come from a C# objects so I know the advantages of this rigid structure well. What I was looking for here was a quick ("scripty"?) way to get what I wanted at the command line. I agree that if this was required in a production script we should use objects/properties as they are more maintainable

Comment: The one thing to watch with Out-String is that it truncates at 80 characters by default.  I normally do blah | Out-String -Width 1kb or -Width 10kb to avoid this.

Answer (score 19):

Just ***forget it*** :o)

Outputs *are* objects. You are right, and you are going to use this.

So [mjolinor has the shortest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635059/filter-the-output-of-a-command-as-if-it-was-text/6635212#6635212), but for your knowledge just test:

```
Get-Service | Get-Member
```

So you will understand that

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.name -match ".*sql.*" }
```

also works, and there you've got your text as a *property* of the object.

Answer (score 16):

Most answers here focus on finding the service name with "sql" in the name, not on filtering *the entire* output *as if it was text*. Also, the accepted answer uses a non-PowerShell function, "findstr".

So, granted, what follows is not the most elegant solution, but for sake of completeness I would like to provide the 100% PowerShell solution that takes the question of the OP literally:

```
(get-Service | Out-String) -split "`r`n" | Select-String sql
```

- We need [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Out-String), because using the solutions provided in other answers doesn't provide us the full text output of the [Get-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service) command, only the `Name` parameter.
- We need to split on newlines, because [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String) seems to treat the entire text as one long string, and returns it as a whole, if "sql" is found in it.
- I use Select-String instead of [findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), because findstr is not a PowerShell function.

This is a purist answer, and in practice, for this specific use-case, I would not recommend it. But for people coming here through Google Search based on the question title, this is a more accurate answer...

Comment: Thank you so much for your concise explanation. Really helped me out.  But why did you have to place the first pipe in parentheses?

Comment: You could test this by removing them. Then you will find that removing the parentheses causes the -split parameter to be applied directly to the Out-String cmdlet, and not to the result of (get-Service | Out-String).

Comment: According to the documentation, ```Out-String``` converts the output to a single string. To produce a string per line, one can use ```-stream```, ending up with 

```get-service | out-string -stream | select-string 'sql'```.

Answer (score 15):

```
Get-Service | Select-String -Pattern "sql"
```

This works just like [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep). And you can even sort:

```
Get-Service | Select-String -Pattern "sql" | sort
```

Comment: is there any reason this would not work in PS2? Per my $PSVersionTable.PSVersion. I am like original OP, I cannot get it to work, here I tried a 'simple' one, "event" or "event*" for the event log , and though get-service works the subset returns nil. ty!

Answer (score 10):

You're working way too hard at it:

```
Get-Service *sql*
```

Comment: This answer is actually wrong. What this does is search through the .Name parameters of the objects, but not through all parameters shown in the text output. So "Get-service *Stopped*" returns nothing, while "Get-Service | out-string | findstr Stopped" would. This was OP's question...

Comment: To be clear, when searching for a specific service your approach makes far more sense. But if the question is "how to search the output as if it where text" it won't have the desired results. I won't downvote because it's a valuable answer, and might have been what OP is realy looking for.

Comment: Comments to Wouter's comments?

Comment: @PeterMortensen - Nope. Three solid years of surgery, chemo, radiation and immuno therapy have me down to 112 lbs, one good arm, and all the patience God gave hot nitroglycerin. This fell off the bottom of the last page of my Big Book of Hills To Die On a long time ago.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone wants more information on logical operations, please see *[Using the Where-Object Cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ee177028(v=technet.10))*:

• -lt -- Less than

• -le -- Less than or equal to

• -gt -- Greater than

• -ge -- Greater than or equal to

• -eq -- Equal to

• -ne -- Not equal to

• -like - Like; uses wildcards for pattern matching

`Get-Service | where {$_ -match 'sql'}` would be `Get-Service | where {$_ -eq "sql"}`

`Get-Service | where {$_ -like 'sql'}` would be `Get-Service | where {$_ -like "sql"}`

And now an actual example.

```
PS C:\> Get-Service | where {$_.name -like "net*"}

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  Net Driver HPZ12   Net Driver HPZ12
Running  Netlogon           Netlogon
```

Comment: `-notlike` is there also, which does what you'd expect. also needs wildcards to be any different from `-ne` - similar to the relationship between `-like` and `-eq`

Answer (score 3):

That the text of the name is a property of the object is important to get your head around, and how to use the property values in a filter.

Another aspect of PowerShell you can leverage to solve this is selecting properties out of objects with [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-Object) (alias `select`):

```
Get-Service | select -expand name
```

will get you a string array with the names of the servers, and two of your original three filters would work on that. The `-like` isn't going to work, because there's no wildcards in the test string. The only thing it will ever match is just 'sql'.

I still believe [the first solution I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635059/filter-the-output-of-a-command-as-if-it-was-text/6635212#6635212) is best. It's important to know how to do late filtering, but also how to use early filtering when you can.

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
Get-Service| Out-String -stream | Select-String sql
```

where the key point is that -stream option converts the Out-String output in separate lines of text.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to list all services with "sql" in the service name, just use:

```
 get-service -name *sql*
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
Function Select-ObjectPropertyValues {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [String]
        $Pattern,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $input
    )

    $input | Where-Object {($_.PSObject.Properties | Where-Object {$_.Value -match $Pattern} | Measure-Object).count -gt 0} | Write-Output
}
```

Here we are going though each property of an object to see if it matches the given pattern. If the object contains one or more such properties, we write it out. End result: grep by all properties of an object.

Put it in your configuration files and grep to your heart's content.